# Incorporating 3rd party components into packages

Tags: macos, installation, osx-gatekeeper

We receive drivers and utilities from a partner vendor which we distribute with our software.  What are our options for receiving them so they can be easily included in our signed flat package?

We'd rather reduce work at our end and if possible preserve the original vendor's signatures.  We would like to avoid delivering two packages for a smoother user experience.  It seems that flat packages and other deployable product archives are not convenient because they cannot be included in another flat package.

EDIT: 
This app won't be distributed via the app store. 
The drivers and utilities need to be available to everyone on the system.
It will probably be installed via an installer, unless there is a way to make the drivers and utilities available to everyone using drag and drop.

Comment: is this an app you will want to distribute via the app store?  does this app get installed via an installer or via drag & drop, or?  do you want the drivers and utilities to only be available to your app, or to everybody / everything on the system (i.e. installed in "`/Library`")?

Comment: Just updated the question with more information.